# «Не познанный» или «непознанный»?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные, причастия

*Очевидно, что второй способ крайне опасен, так как является грубым вмешательством в естественную, **до конца (не)познанную** логику очень сложного механизма.*

Прошу однозначного ответа. В тексте написано слитно, а я думаю, что нужно раздельно: есть зависимое слово. В Викисловаре слово «познанный» указано как причастие, «непознанный» – как прилагательное. Нацкорпус, как известно, далеко не всегда может помочь.

**Примеры раздельного написания:**

*В её истории есть некий **до конца не познанный мною** нюанс...* [Сергей Есин. Марбург (2005)]

***Не познанная еще**, вялая мысль...* [Виктор Астафьев. Пастух и пастушка. Современная пастораль (1967-1989)]

*Я тоже почувствовала давно забытое, или **не познанное ранее**, волнение...* [Виктория Токарева. Летающие качели (1978)]

**Примеры слитного написания:**

*И пусть для человеческих масс власть ― вечный атрибут нашей жизни, на деле она собою являет **еще непознанный нами** феномен.* [Леонид Зорин. Юпитер (2001) // «Знамя», 2002]

*Что в нашей жизни сказка, а что **непознанная пока** реальность?* [Константин Серафимов. Экспедиция во мрак (1978-1996)]

*Было в ней что-то неизвестное, что-то **еще непознанное***… [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Дело об убийстве, или Отель «У погибшего альпиниста» (1970)]

Comment: Согласен с вами. Там явно отрицание, а не утверждение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непознанное — необъяснимое, мистическое, таинственное.
Не познанное — то, что еще не было понято, узнано, пережито, опробовано.

В её истории есть некий до конца не познанный мною нюанс... [Сергей Есин. Марбург (2005)] (Этот нюанс не является таинственным и мистическим, а просто человек еще не разобрался.)

Я тоже почувствовала давно забытое, или не познанное ранее, волнение... [Виктория Токарева. Летающие качели (1978)] (Волнение не переживалось ранее, а не таинственное, необъяснимое и мистическое.)

Что в нашей жизни сказка, а что непознанная пока реальность? [Константин Серафимов. Экспедиция во мрак (1978-1996)] (Необъяснимая, таинственная и мистическая реальность.)

Было в ней что-то неизвестное, что-то еще непознанное… [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Дело об убийстве, или Отель «У погибшего альпиниста» (1970)] (В ней было что-то необъяснимое и таинственное.)

Трудности еще возникают из-за того, что в некоторых ситуациях эти два значения могут переплетаться: необъяснимое, мистическое и таинственное потому, что мы еще не изучили это или не узнали некую информацию об этом, — так что в некоторых ситуациях справедливы оба варианта или исходящий из тонких представлений автора об обозначаемом данным словом.

Ах да, совсем забыл про предложение в вопросе. Написание раздельно, так как тут обозначается то, что логика была не до конца изучена, а не то, что она была необъяснимой, таинственной и мистической.

Comment: Спасибо, Jim Korbett. Разбираться в тонкостях смысла не было и нет пока времени, поэтому и задал вопрос. Буду осмысливать позже...

Answer (score 1):

*Очевидно, что второй способ крайне опасен, так как является грубым вмешательством **в естественную, до конца (не)познанную логику** очень сложного механизма.*

1. Итак, задача решается только **в общем виде** (отрицание или утверждение), правило никакое нельзя подобрать? А может быть,  попробовать.
2. Если это **созданный людьми механизм,** то, скорее всего, логика у него вполне познаваемая, просто еще не понятая до конца. Тогда это очевидное причастие, которое пишется с НЕ раздельно при наличии зависимых слов.
3. Но есть и другие случаи. Может быть, это такое явление, которое **в принципе непознаваемо.** Как говорят философы, невозможно до конца познать законы системы, если наблюдатель сам находится внутри этой системы. *Что в нашей жизни сказка, а что непознанная пока реальность? Или вообще непознаваемая?*
4. И тогда это **отпричастное прилагательное с переносным**, а не прямым значением, а на них зависимые слова не действуют. Такие прилагательные имеют синонимы:  *непознаваемый, неизвестный, таинственный*, также возможны однородные отношения с такими прилагательными.

Другие примеры отпричастных прилагательных: *Все считали его невыдержанным в спорах и грубым в манерах. Вы – неприспособленные к жизни цветы.*

5. Эти варианты **нужно различать при редактировании** – вдруг там говорится как раз о таком случае. Здесь нужен контекст: почему логика названа **естественной**, может быть, речь идет **об органической материи**, а там достаточно непознаваемых тайн.

Да, ошибки возможны…  Вот так задумаешься, спать не будешь :))

Comment: Ждал вашего ответа, Sharon, спасибо! Речь идет о дыхании, весь текст довольно туманный. *"Согласно приведенной модели, существуют два способа сознательного упраления процессом дыхания: а) через механизм регуляции и восстановления; б) «непосредственно». Очевидно, что второй способ крайне опасен..."*

Comment: Да уж,  я бы тогда не стала исправлять  – специалистам виднее, по интуиции, может, пишут.  Впрочем, в  глаза не бросается...  А почему сразу не ответила, так желающих ответить было много, а вы же торопились...  А дело тут тонкое, требует индивидуального подхода.

Comment: Не бросается в глаза слитное написание?  Желающих ответить как раз было не много, а я ждал четыре дня, прежде чем принять ответ Jim'а :) А на счет специалистов – там достаточно неграмотно построенных предложений, неправильных окончаний и "грязи" в оформлении.

Comment: Я бы написала слитно, так как познаваемость логики естественных процессов, да еще "до конца", нам никто не гарантирует, а рассчитывать мы можем только на гипотезы и модели, которые проверяем на практике.  Вот и весь процесс "познания".  А в глаза не бросается форма с раздельным НЕ, она используется с  большей частотностью  Так что спать можно спокойно:)).  А Jim  написал бы мне пару страниц комментариев, если бы я раньше ответила, так что пусть порадуется, что его ответ принят. Но вы-то, я надеюсь, ничем не огорчены?

Comment: Спасибо еще раз! Конечно ничем! А принятый ответ на самом деле помог, дал почву для раздумий.

Comment: У меня часто так бывает. Спорю со всеми, ни с кем не соглашаюсь, думаю, что только я права. А потом начинаю думать, оценивать, и оказывается, что права я только наполовину, а участники  помогли мне увидеть проблему в целом.  И тогда я с удовольствием складываю полученные знания в копилку,  считая их все своей собственностью, а как поступают они – не знаю...

Answer (score 1):

Надо пытаться проверять подстановкой глаголов *быть/являться* (здесь не подходит без изменения структуры) либо причастия *являющийся*:
*до конца не являющуюся познанной логику;

до конца являющуюся непознанной логику*. || Понятно, что это некорректно.

Как-то так ещё бы сошло:
*вконец являющуюся непознанной*. || То есть "окончательно", "полностью", а не "до конца".

*Непознанный до конца* (так люди не говорят) = непознанный аж до самого конца, полностью (ничего не познано).
*Не познанный до конца* = тот, который до конца не познали, но познали до какой-то степени.
То есть, как видим, есть большая разница в смысле. Первый (несмотря на то, что люди так не говорят — нарушение стилистики) в данном примере не подходит, потому что очевидно, что логика этого механизма хоть как-то была уже познана.

Для ясности понимания можно "до конца" заменить синонимом "целиком".

Comment: Спасибо за участие! Я пока остаюсь на позиции раздельного написания, потому что это "до конца" у меня никак не вяжется со слитным прилагательным "непознанный".

Comment: А я на позиции того, что слитное написание некорректно, так что наши позиции совпадают.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец "До конца непознанную" могло бы означать "аж до конца непознанную", но люди так не говорят от слова совсем. И без этого "аж" оно так вообще не воспринимается. Для этого необходимо ударение на "конца", и частица "аж" как раз его обеспечивает.

Comment: Спасибо, мне уже все ясно. Я знаю, в чем была моя ошибка, но не в том ,что вы думаете. Если сказать коротко:  грамматика не может выразить тонкие смысловые оттенки, там все проще.  Поэтому я убираю свои комментарии, а вы как хотите.

Answer (score 1):

**Второй ответ** (допустимо ли слитное написание НЕ с причастиями при наличии зависимых слов)

(1) *Что в нашей жизни сказка, а что **непознанная пока** реальность?*

(2) *Что в нашей жизни сказка, а что реальность, которую мы пока **не познали**.*

1. НЕ с глаголом пишется раздельно – **отрицание действия**.
2. **Причастие это форма глагола.** Одиночные причастия сближаются с прилагательными и допускают слитное написание НЕ. При появлении зависимых слов действие проявлено в большей степени,  признаки глагола усиливаются и требуется раздельное написание НЕ.

Это общее правило, если мы имеем дело с причастием.

3. А если автор написал НЕ слитно, исходя из **мистических представлений в своей голове,** то это будет **авторская орфография**, и ничто иное.
4. Поэтому не надо делать вид, что эта орфография соответствует официальным правилам письма и **как-то оправдывать ее**. (**Такой подход** к решению задачи я вижу в первом ответе.)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, буду думать. Мне оформление проекта перестало нравиться: надо половину выбросить и картинками украсить. Знания нуждаются в красивой обертке. Так что еще и художник нужен. А вот непознанная реальность вопросы вызывает у МЕНЯ, и я обозначила какие. Мистическая философия вещь интересная, но к орфографии ее лучше не пристраивать. Ссылку на нее не дашь. Поэтому первый ответ излишне философского характера мне перестал нравиться. А вам? Вы считаете такое письмо авторским или нормальным?

Comment: Часто не вижу у вас в ответах чётких позиций, из-за чего не понимаю их общий смысл. Может, надо меньше художественности, а больше научной конкретики, чёткости мысли. Какое письмо? Я рассматривал только пример про сложный механизм, о котором спрашивается. Если про "непознанная пока реальность", то там всё нормально, зависимые слова, указывающие на время, наоборот, способствуют слитному написанию.

Comment: "Не познанная пока реальность". Это причастие, зависимое слово есть? Вот и пишите раздельно.

Comment: Надо с умом подходить. У Розенталя есть пример "*веками нетронутая земля*".

Comment: Да, здесь уже ум потребовался?  В этом примере метафора, переносное значение (века не могут трогать землю). А у вас что, тоже метафора? Кто реальность познает? Человек! Так что производитель действия  имеется. Причастие это самое натуральное.

Comment: Смысл такой: реальность пока что (какая?) непознанная, но дальше ситуация может измениться.

Comment: Ну да, картина пока ненаписанная, но все может измениться. Есть разница? Я не вижу.  Грамматика не видит тоже.  Это же форма, а всё остальное для нее лексическое наполнение, и не более того!

Comment: Кто трогает землю? Человек! Так что производитель действия тоже имеется. Там смысл никак не в том, что века не трогают, века всё трогают, да уж, и как вы могли так понять... Если бы века не трогали, то точно бы писалось раздельно, а века там указывают на время (очень долго). Играет роль слово, "ненаписанная" как качество плохо выглядит стилистически, да и краткая форма желательна: *картина пока не написана*.

Comment: То есть всё сложно (много нюансов), но не для меня.

Comment: Очень, очень неубедительно!  Сами же видите: стиль, краткая форма, что еще придумаете, чтобы обойти самое простое правило? А по поводу нюансов развлеку вас рассказиком. Мальчик с помощью волшебной флейты должен был превратить шишку в лягушку. Через минуту появились лапки, и вот  она запрыгала к траве. Ну как? –  спросил довольный отличник. – Вы меня грандиозно разочаровали, ответил учитель. Это не лягушка, а банальная жаба. И запомните: мастерство – в нюансах, а все остальное доступно любому ремесленнику.

Comment: Если честно, я их не различаю, вроде как лягушки меньше. Да, мастерство в нюансах. И в данной теме надо их чувствовать. Ничего не обхожу, без краткой формы плохо звучит, у Розенталя есть исключения, где зависимые слова указывают на время.

Comment: Ладно, так и скажите редактору, когда он спросит вас про слитное НЕ:  Я чувствую, что это исключение. И при этом смотрите ему прямо в глаза, не отрываясь.  Возможно, это подействует. НО вот как вы убедите меня, что вы идеально знаете орфографию.

Comment: Да подстановкой глагола: *картина пока является ненаписанной* (не говорят так люди); *реальность пока является непознанной, а потом может стать познанной*.

Comment: Интересно, кто автор этого странного способа проверки подстановкой слова "является". Наверное, фокусник или воспитатель младшей детской группы в яслях.  Вы как думаете?

Comment: Школьный метод, надёжный и универсальный.

Comment: Ага, а еще мистический, таинственный и до конца непознанный. Нет ни логики, ни теории, ни здравого смысла. В общем, чего ни хватишься, ничего нет!  рекомендуется в особых случаях, эффективность применения крайне низкая.

Comment: Ничего лучше вы не найдёте. *До конца непознанный* = полностью непознанный — здесь точно не подходит, даже не учитывая стилистику.

Comment: " ...в естественную, до конца (не)познанную логику очень сложного механизма..." .Согласен с вами. Там явно ОТРИЦАНИЕ, а не утверждение. – 
oleedd  ЭТО ВЫ ПИСАЛИ? А почему теперь у вас слитное написание?  Тоже мистика?

Comment: В плане стилистики слитное написание неправильное. А вне стилистики, только в плане смысла слитное не подходит в вашем примере: *Ага, а еще мистический, таинственный и до конца непознанный.* Что не так?

Comment: В прошлый раз вы правильно сделали, когда дали ссылку на каталог всех страниц. Как-то мне не нравится звучание "***по теме** русского языка*". Примеры: *работы по математике, работа на такую-то тему*, но *не работы по теме математики*.

Comment: Посмотрите сейчас. Но мне кажется,  особого толку не будет. А у меня появилась идея, как различить варианты с раздельным и слитным написанием НЕ (Буриданов осел подсказал). Орфография должна быть точной наукой, а не субъективным толкованием отдельных признаков.

Comment: Лучше, но не всё гладко. На основе правил, но "на основе правил, систематизированных и дополненных" — уже не основа, а сам материал. Это смахивает на логическую ошибку. "Правил" с маленькой надо, не вижу причин для большой. "Школа русского письма" — пафосно (даже перебор), это как плюс, но так говорят про собственную школу, где как бы всё своё. Школа должна включать всё-всё, а у вас только 41 тема. "Школа" употребляют для практических дисциплин (см. пункт 4 у Кузнецова). Пунктуация не входит в правописание (в словаре это =орфография), а вы говорите только о ней. Добавьте лучше "мой" где-то.

Comment: Ничего не поняла. Школа русского письма - многозначное понятие, к тому же оно давно используется.   Я точно следую  правилам, это важно, только систематизирую их  и добавляю грамматические определения.  Все это мелочи, непринципиально,  но будет ли толк от этого.  Наш форум не особо известен,  писатели туда не ходят, а мои читатели неизвестно откуда берутся. Нужно социальные сети привлекать, но я там не участвую. Что делать? Найти кого-нибудь и заплатить за рекламную статью?  Написать-то я ее могу сама.

Comment: Ваша структура равносильна "*на основе систематизированных и дополненных правил Розенталя*". Но основа же у вас просто правила. Можно после Розенталя добавить "что": *на основе правил Розенталя, что систематизированы и дополнены*. "Школа русского письма" — 6 результатов в Гугл, среди которых есть ваши статьи. Почему "правил" с большой? Какое правило? Правописание — только орфография. Вы чего хотите? Чтоб люди комментировали статьи? Можно заплатить за рекламу, таким не занимался, Гугл в помощь, но рекламировать надо на лингвистических сайтах. Реклама — это не дёшево.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо, пусть все остается как есть и САМО О СЕБЕ  заботится. А я пока займусь доработкой материала, там еще хватает проблем. Все должно быть проще и лучше.

Comment: Александр, лучше не читайте,  там все очень сложносочиненно, да еще я самое главное и принципиальное сказать не успела. Это надо было додумать до конца, а меня все время перебивали.

Comment: А вам всё в этой теме ясно?  Никаких вопросов не осталось? До конца не познанная логика очень сложного механизма. До конца не познанная логика.  Они одинаково пишутся?